# How to change email associated with Google Play Games profile?

Tags: email, google, google-play-games

I've got games linked to my Google Play Games Gamer ID, which is associated with a Gmail email. Is it possible to change the email the Gamer ID is linked to?

Comment: Not possible at all. The ID is associated with the Google account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still change **login email** in Google Account settings page.
Changing linked account is not currently possible.